# how can i grab all selected check box values on submit action using angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image] when i checked checkbox am getting error in console. i have enclosed screen shot .how can i grap all slected checkbox values on submit event and how to avoid Cannot assign to read only property 'selected'error

```js
angular
    .module('test1')
    .controller('Test1Controller', [
        '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window',
        function($scope, $http, $location, $window) {

            var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem("storeid");
            $http.get('***').success(function(data, status, response)
            {
                $scope.items = (JSON.stringify(data[0].D_Services).replace(/\"/g, "")).split(',');
                console.log($scope.items);
                //console i'm getting ["Tyres", "Spares", "Accessories"]
                $scope.selected = [];
            });
            $scope.check = function(data)
            {
                var arr = [];
                for (var i in data) {
                    if (data[i].SELECTED == 'Y') {
                        arr.push(data[i].item);
                    }
                }
                console.log(arr);
                $scope.selected = arr;
            }

        }
    ]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="Test1Controller" data-ng-init="loadservice()">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"  ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/> {{item}}
</div>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check(items)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you going to assign a `selected` *property* to a simple array value? You need an array of objects (`[{name: "Tyres", selected: false}, ..]`)

Comment: okey how can i grap all selected values

Comment: `var selectedItems = $scope.items.map(function(item) { if (item.selected) return item.name; });`

Comment: can you please explain me clearly .i am new to javascript

Comment: Do you wanna achieve something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/nLC3g/475/

Comment: yes but  $scope.items i am getting from database(mongodb).in console my $scope.items showiing like this ["Tyres", "Spares", "Accessories"] .

Comment: I have updated my fiddle, is that working for you?

Comment: glad to help, give a tick if solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a modal data and append it to $scope.items

```
var serverData = ["Tyres", "Spares", "Accessories"]; //assuming this is server data
$scope.items = [];

for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
    var modal = {
        name: serverData[i],
        selected: false
    };
    $scope.items.push(modal);
}
```

updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/nLC3g/477/